# Serialization by pydantic in fastapi

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

[Relation in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249652/relation-in-sqlalchemy/72251007#72251007)

I'll ask this question separately, since it's a continuation of this one, but with a different content.
I want to serialize a join and then serialize it with pydantic, but it doesn't work.
If possible, I want to return it as if it were a single object.

```
{
 id: 1,
 parent_column: test1,
 child_column: test2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Pydantic model with the information you want, so the model will take care of the serialization to JSON format.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    parent: str
    child: str
```

You just have to create a response from your model by providing it with the data in the requested format.

```py
data_json = MyResponse(id= my_data.id, parent=my_data.parent, child=my_data.child)
```

Below is an example given with a fastAPI endpoint that would take an ID to retrieve a specific data and return a JSON response with a specific template.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import status

class MyResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    parent: str
    child: str


@ router.get('/data',
             status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
             response_model=MyResponse)
def get_data(parent_id:int):
    try:
        data = get_data(parent_id)
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,detail="Server Error")

    return MyResponse(id=data.id, parent=data.parent, child=data.child)
```

Afterwards, it is possible to link Pydantic models with sqlalchemy via the `orm_mode` of the Pydantic class. More information here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#use-pydantics-orm_mode